# as/400 rpg /free d-spec to dcl-s spec with pointer based

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

On the AS/400 in RGP I have the following statement

D DataAttribute   s          16383c   based(p_Attr)

I need it translated into the /free version

dcl-s    DataAttribute    ucs2(16383)    based(p_attr);
I have this statement but the complier does not like the based keyword "based".

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Edit your question.  Tell us the compiler version - it's right on the listing.  You need to be on v7.1 or higher with the proper compiler PTF to support fully free RPG.  Also tell us the exact error message, like 'RNF1234 Keyword BASED not allowed.'

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me.

What error message are you getting?

Are you sure you have the PTFs needed for free format D-specs?